# ElasticSearch: Combining bool and script_score in a single query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an existing elastic bool query.  I've added a dense vector field to the index and would like to search it all in one query. The compound query part of the Elastic docs seems to imply you can do this, but I can't make it work (I get a runtime error) and haven't been able to find any examples.  Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying.

```
localQuery = {
            'bool': 
                'should': [
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "field1": {
                                "query": query,
                                "boost": 10
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "field2": {
                                "query": query,
                                "boost": 6
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                         "script_score": {
                           "query": {
                              "match_all": {}
                            },
                         "script": {
                            "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.element_desc_vector, 
                                                       'description_vec') + 1.0",
                            "params": {"element_desc_vector": queryList}
                         }
                      }
                   }
               ]
             }
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions, pointers to examples or even a flat "no you can't do that".

Thanks
Howard

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do the same, I eventually found you could [access the score from within the script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/modules-scripting-fields.html#scripting-score). So you could add the score returned in the "should" clause to that of the cosine similarity.
Also I put the bool clause inside the script_score and not vice-versa.

```
local_query = {
        "script_score": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "field1": {
                      "query": query,
                      "boost": 10
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "field2": {
                      "query": query,
                      "boost": 6
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "script": {
            "source": "(cosineSimilarity(params.element_desc_vector, 'description_vec') + 1.0) + _score",
            "params": {
              "element_desc_vector": queryList
            }
          }
        }
      }
```